# iOS app freezes after UITableView search

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am a beginner to iOS development and am having trouble finding the cause for this issue.

I have a  simple app with a Master and DetailView controllers. The Master View contains an UITableView with a SearchController. Selecting any row on the UITableView will transition to the detailview.

The app freezes when I perform the following sequence

1. Launch app
2. Pull down the search bar
3. Enter text
4. Select a row from the search results
5. Select back from the detail view

Now the app freezes after the ViewDidLoad method of the MasterView is loaded. I can't find anything in the system.log.

Here's the code from the MasterViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,40)];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;

    // Create and configure the search controller
    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *months = @"Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec";
    feeds = [months componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection");

    if(tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        return feeds.count;
    }

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like %@", self.searchBar.text];
    self.filteredFeeds = [feeds filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showDetail" sender: self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

I have uploaded the entire project at the location below.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yok9vngzv143npa/search.zip

Any kind of assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not able to run your program because version issue of iOS.
But i seen your code. I suspect on 1 point on following code,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,40)];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;

    // Create and configure the search controller
    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
}
```

**You create/allocate UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController again and again while you get back from DetailViewController to MasterViewController, these may be cause of your app freezing.** 
"viewWillAppear" called before the receiver’s view is about to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for showing the view.
"viewDidLoad" called after view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory.

I suggest you place your one time allocations view code in viewDidLoad method.

For more information go through this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad